# python's counterpart for Ruby String#succ?

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is a function (or method) in python that increments strings as in Ruby's [String#succ](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-succ) method, ie:

```
~ $ irb --simple-prompt
>> '2'.succ
=> "3"
>> '99'.succ
=> "100"
>> 'zzz'.succ
=> "aaaa"
>>
```

Comment: Not out of the box, no. You'd have to code your own.

Comment: It always puzzled me why `'zzz'.succ` should return `'aaaa'`. That entirely depends on the locale. In Danish, for instance, it should probably return `'ååå'`, since `å` is treated as a separate letter that goes after `z`.

Comment: @Denis it's because it's implemented based on the character set and not the actual alphabet (which is of course locale dependent).

Comment: Using a method like so does not seem very pythonic.  Maybe you should re think it?

Comment: @agconti not very pythonic? maybe or maybe not, but that's not the criteria I use to build applications and not should yours. I believe in the algorithm being used, that's a good place to start, so feel free to criticize my algorithm. pythonic … that's just marketing, same for "rubyist", at the end performance, good algorithms and clean code it's what really matters.

Comment: @Kira If you're choosing to implement in python you should break from your ruby way of thinking. Why? Because, efficient python implementation and collaboration with other python developers depends on that. Of course you can achieve the same result from many different implementations, but it doesn't mean that the one you are most personally comfortable with is the best. I'm a huge fan of the power of expression you can achieve in ruby, but python isn't the same and that should be respected.

Comment: Pythonic isn't a marketing term but a mantra used by python programers to strive to achieve the most efficient and expressive code that is most true to the core python language.

Answer (score 1):

The following implementation is the closest that I could get with the ruby's implementation of  String#succ

```
def succ(s):
    if not isinstance(s, (str,string)):
        raise TypeError("succ works only with strings")
    if not s: return
    if max(map(ord, s)) > 127:
        raise TypeError("succ currently only supports ascii")

    #Three different character category honoured
    #  1. ascii lowercase alpha
    #  2. ascii uppercase alpha
    #  3. digits
    #  4. ascii nonalpha characters (the entire ascii set)
    lower = string.ascii_lowercase + 'a'
    upper = string.ascii_uppercase + 'A'
    digits = string.digits + '0'
    nonalpha = map(chr, range(0, 256)) + [chr(0)]
    def incr(ch):
        '''
        Generates the next character in sequence using the following rules
            1. Incrementing a digit always results in another digit
            2. Incrementing a letter results in another letter of the same case.
            3. Incrementing nonalphanumerics uses the underlying
               character set’s collating sequence.
        '''
        if ch.isdigit(): return digits[ord(ch) - ord("0") + 1]
        if ch.islower(): return lower[ord(ch) - ord('a') + 1]
        if ch.isupper(): return upper[ord(ch) - ord('A') + 1]
        return nonalpha[ord(ch) + 1]
    def last(ch):
        '''
        Returns the last character in its catagory
        '''
        if ch.isdigit(): return digits[-2]
        if ch.islower(): return lower[-2]
        if ch.isupper(): return upper[-2]
        return nonalpha[-2]
    def first(ch):
        '''
        Returns the last first in its catagory
        '''
        if ch.isdigit(): return digits[0]
        if ch.islower(): return lower[0]
        if ch.isupper(): return upper[0]
        return nonalpha[0]
    def islast(ch):
        '''
        Checks if next increment would generate a carry
        '''
        return ch == last(ch)
    s = list(s)[::-1]
    carry = True
    try:
        index = next(i for i, e in enumerate(s) if e.isalnum())
    except StopIteration:
        index = 0
    while carry:

        if index == len(s): #Add a character for Overflow
            s.append(first(s[index - 1]))
            break
        carry =  True if islast(s[index]) else False
        s[index] = incr(s[index])
        index += 1
    return ''.join(s[::-1])
```

**Example Usage**

```
succ('2')       - > 3         
succ('99')      - > 000       
succ('zzz')     - > aaaa      
succ('')        - > None      
succ('abcd')    - > abce      
succ('THX1138') - > THX1139   
succ('<<koala>>') - > <<koalb>> 
succ('1999zzz') - > 2000aaa   
succ('ZZZ9999') - > AAAA0000  
succ('***')     - > **+
```

Comment: I have not test this code yet, I may end up pushing your code inside my application, many thanks Abhijit. Just one more thing so I can accept you answer, could you please edit your answer and explicitly state the lack of this function on the python's built-in library, in that way my question will be fully answered.