# Understanding String#succ

Tags: python, ruby

I am not a Ruby Programmer, but while trying to answer this Question [python's counterpart for Ruby String#succ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721214/pythons-counterpart-for-ruby-stringsucc), I tried to understand how the Ruby's implementation works. I then referred the doc [succ → new_str](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-succ), I realized, all the examples does conform to the description, except

```
"<<koala>>".succ   #=> "<<koalb>>"
```

My Python implementation returns

```
>>> succ("<<koala>>")
'<<koala>?'
```

By adopting the three succession rules

1. Incrementing a digit always results in another digit
2. Incrementing a letter results in another letter of the same case.
3. Incrementing nonalphanumerics uses the underlying character set’s collating sequence.

As was interpreted from the docs, yet seeing the above example, it seems I am missing something.

Can someone help me understand the logic behind the above example?

Comment: *starting from the rightmost alphanumeric (or the rightmost character if there are no alphanumerics)*, so you'd have to increment `a`. Only if there are *no* alphanumerics in the string would you increment `>` to the next character.

Comment: Is this a question about Ruby, or about Python? If it is about stating how Ruby's `succ` works, then how to implement that in Python should be an independent question, and should be irrelevant here. Your question is mixed up.

Comment: According to Ruby documentation: *The successor is calculated by incrementing characters starting from the rightmost alphanumeric (or the rightmost character if there are no alphanumerics) in the string.*

Comment: @sawa: Please spend few minutes to read the question before commenting

Comment: @Abhijit I did. But your question did not worth that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually described in the documentation, maybe you misunderstood.

If there are alphanumeric characters, you have to increment from the rightmost one of them (last `"a"` in `"<<koala>>"`).

If there are no alphanumeric characters in the string, you have to increment from the rightmost character in the whole string.

Comment: Thank you. I should had been more careful with the doc :-)